# Cos(z) and Cosh(iz)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I understand that $\cos(z)=\cosh(iz)$ but I was wondering what happened at higher powers of $z$.

E.g does $\cos(z^2)=\cosh(iz^2)$ implying that $\cos(z^n)=\cosh(iz^n)$

Comment: Set $z=y^n$ in the original equation ...

Comment: Well, yes. That's how composition of functions (or call it "substitution principle" or "putting stuff into stuff") works.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$It might be more clear if in the first equation we use a different variable besides $z$. I'll use $w$. We know $\cos w = \cosh(iw)$ for any and all complex numbers $w \in \C$. Hence if I have another complex number $z$, then $z^2, z^3, ..., z^n$ are also all complex numbers since raising a complex number to a positive integer yields another complex number. So all of these $z^n$'s are valid values for $w$ in our first equation and can be plugged in. Hence
\begin{align*}
\cos(z^n) = \cosh(iz^n)
\end{align*}